# jquery bootbox screen is greyed out

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

I am using `bootbox.confirm` with an ajax call, and I get the confirm box, but my screen is greyed out and I'm unable to select anything.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

My first thought is that maybe my scripts are referenced wrong in `_Layout`, but I'm not sure:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

**Bundles**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
    "~/Scripts/moment.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
    "~/Scripts/Scripts.js"
);

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootbox.js",
    "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

When inspecting here is what I have:

```
<body class="modal-open">

<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
<div class="modal-dialog">...</div>
```

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var table = $("#Table").DataTable();

    $("#Table.js-delete").on("click",
        function () {

            var link = $(this);
            $("body").removeClass("modal-open");


            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?",
                function (result) {

                    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/Informations/" + $(this).attr("data-id"),
                            method: "DELETE",
                            success: function () {
                                table.row(link.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                                link.parents("tr").remove();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


            });
    });
```

Comment: that almost seems like a z-index thing where everything shows up at the same time and its just out of order

Comment: @Keith so what do you recommend?

Comment: @Keith in bootstrap.css.. the class for `.modal-backdrop` has a z-index of 1040

Comment: jQuery UI and Bootbox don't normally play well together, as some of their CSS classes and JavaScript functions clash. I would recommend using one or the other, or checking out [jQuery UI Bootstrap](http://jquery-ui-bootstrap.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/) (although that hasn't been updated in a while).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please do inspect element check out classes applied to modal and main body in your page,i'm pretty sure this is because modal-backdrop active and stucked
here are few things you can do

1) just add data-dismiss="modal" to button

2)If modal hide or visible, faded background is remained and does not let you click any where you can forcefully remove those by using below piece of code.

first hide your modal div element.

```
$('modalId').modal('hide');
```

secondly remove 'modal-open' class from body and '.modal-backdrop' at the end of the page.

```
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Comment: first hide your modal div element. $('#modalId').modal('hide');

Comment: Where do I put that? Also, I don't have a modalid.. this modal is created on the fly with bootbox

Comment: share your full code or make jsfiddle so that i can look into it

Comment: when you say full code, do you mean the script that I have already put at the top? or what?

Comment: your html and scripts associated with your modal pop up

Comment: I created a test [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq3qhgrg/).. when you click 'Delete' everything else becomes un-selectable.. but you don't see the modal for some reason

Comment: Okay, I just updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7m5rwou1/).. and it's working appropriately

Comment: I fixed it, in my css, i just changed the z-index to 0 for `.modal-bootstrap`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  You can try this please:

View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index58</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btn").click(function () {
                bootbox.confirm("This is the default confirm!",
                    function (result) {
                        console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);
                    });
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="ShowModal" id="btn" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```